# Action Required Switch to the Play Referrer API by March 1, 2020

Tags: android, google-play

I got the email from Google as follows: -

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> We recently announced that we’ll be deprecating the install_referrer
>   intent broadcast mechanism. Because one or more of your apps uses this
>   intent to track referrals, we wanted to ensure you make the switch
>   before March 1, 2020. After this date, new versions of the Play Store
>   app will no longer broadcast the install_referrer intent after app
>   installs.
>
> Action required
>
> Migrate to the Play Install Referrer API to track your app installs
>   for the following apps and/or games.

But in my application I am not using it any where. What could be the possible reason for this warning?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59279487/7316675

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install referrer intent deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59274930/install-referrer-intent-deprecation)

Comment: I answered a different question with information how to find out which of your libraries makes use of the install_referrer broadcast by looking into the manifest merger blame file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59304328/810019

Comment: Hey thanks for your comments. The solution given here are changes related to our code. But my point is, if I haven't implemented in my code then why to do changes. In my case Firebase is using it and I am sure in next updates they will fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I checked with Firebase support for this, as I can see firebase libraries are using install_referrer. Got below response from them:

> This is a great catch. Thanks for bringing this to our attention. I'm currently in discussion with our Analytics experts and will get back within 48 hours, or as soon as I have more information. For now, no need for any action from your end, wait for the next update from the Firebase team.

I think we should wait for the next update for firebase libraries, they might fix it. We have the deadline of March 1st, 2020. I think it is enough for the firebase team to update the libraries.

If you have used this API in your code by yourself, then you need to change it immediately as you are not depending on firebase or any other third party library provider.

Comment: **02/02/2020** and Firebase still keeps the `Play Install Referrer API` permission in their libraries

Comment: anyone have any news?

Comment: exclude play-services-measurement related all modules from firebase.

Answer (score 0):

com.google.firebase:firebase-core and com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics using this broadcast intent internally. You can check it by merged manifest in android manifest file.
This receiver is using install-referrer intent.

**com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver**

Either We can directly remove this explicitly by adding below line in android manifest.xml file but it will lead to **disrupt the install referrer mechanism** in case if your app is using conversion tracking or any other install campaign or we should wait for the next update of firebase libraries.

```
  <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
            tools:remove="android:permission" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"
                    tools:node="remove" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I know about this, I alreday mentioned in my answer. Just wait for Firebase update and issue will be fixed.

Comment: I updated it to version 17.2.2 but still find com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER did you solve it ?

Answer (score -1):

Exclude all measurement modules form firebase

```
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-measurement-api'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-measurement'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-measurement-sdk'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-measurement-impl'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-measurement-sdk-api'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-measurement-base'
}
```