# How to set install referrer url, so the referrer library can consume it

Tags: android, install-referrer

I am referring to an other app, but that app doesn't receive my referrer url. It keeps showing the url that's shown after a normal installation from the PlayStore.

I can find lots of explanations for the receiving app, on how to [read the referrerUrl](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library) with the "new" referrer library, but nothing on how to set my url when referring to an other app.

I expected that I wouldn't have to change anything. It used to work with the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri.Builder uriBuilder = Uri.parse(PLAY_STORE_BASE_URL + TARGET_APP_BUNDLE_ID)
            .buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(REFERRER_KEY, myUrl);

intent.setData(uriBuilder.build());
context.startActivity(intent);
```

when my receiving test app used the now deprecated *com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use app links to pass parameter to android playstore to be retrieved when app is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466443/how-to-use-app-links-to-pass-parameter-to-android-playstore-to-be-retrieved-when)

Comment: I had a typo in my REFERRER_KEY. Thanks. But the linked answer is outdated on the called-app-side, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59279563/action-required-switch-to-the-play-referrer-api-by-march-1-2020